# add document with ReactiveMongo with specified _id

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm trying to insert a new document with _id field specified in ReactiveMongo. But all my inserts are executed with Mongo default incremental objectId. Is there a way to specify _id during insert?

Here is my code.

```
case class MongoId($oid: String)

object MongoId {
  implicit val mongoIdFormat = Json.format[MongoId]
}

case class Person(_id: MongoId, name: String) 

object Person {
  implicit val PersonFormat = Json.format[Person]
}

val collection = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection]("people"))

def save(person: Person) = {
  collection.flatMap(d => d.insert(person)).map(wr => wr.hasErrors match {
    case true => None
    case false => Some(person)
  })
}
```

Comment: Share a reproducer to get help

Answer (score 0):

Sure there's a way. You need to generate the `ObjectId` yourself before inserting in MongoDB. Example below.

```
case class Person (_id: BSONObjectID, name: String)

object Person {
   implicit val PersonFormat = Json.format[Person]
}

val p = Person(BSONObjectID.generate, "Mac")

save(p)
```